# Loading libraries depending on different country - codeigniter (architectural issue)

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries

My application is scaling to multiple countries and controller the users flow is getting hard. The application is built on codeigniter.

I have a `Mother`controller which calls `child` controller to redirect users to the right path depending on the country.

What I would like to do is load different libraries and use functionality depending on the country.

For example, If I have a library called register_fin that has functions to register a user for Finland and also a library called register_den for Dannish user.

I am trying to figure out a way to load different libraries depending on the users path .

The problem is that I don't want to do `if (country ==x) {load library}` which will cause a huge if else issue if there are lets say 20 libraries to load.

I was wondering if the `parent` controller can judge and preload the library from child controller but what I noticed is that when i move to a different controller the library function is not used.

Is there a way to build a controller that can also load libraries depending on the users countries or is there an better alternative to this?

Any advice would be great.